# Add frequency and SD to a summary in R

Tags: r, frequency, summary

I have a data.frame like this (example):

```
product   protein   fat   starch
  aaa        40      5      10
  bbb        50      6      8
  ccc        12      50     4
```

and I want to ask for a summary of this values (min,max,1stQ, 3rdQ..). 
When I run:

```
aggregate(protein~product,summary,data=DATA4, na.rm = TRUE)
```

I have this...

```
    product protein.Min. protein.1st Qu. protein.Median protein.Mean protein.3rd Qu. protein.Max.
      aaa        6.400          14.700         15.600       15.540          16.600       22.500
      bbb        6.300           9.400         10.100       10.130          10.800       15.100
      ccc       23.000          24.080         24.250       24.180          24.420       25.000
```

However I also wanted to have the frequency and SD. How can I ask that?
I tried with ddply but i cannot make it works. (I have NA's in some variables(protein, fat, starch...)

Besides this, and because here i'm only asking a summary for protein levels, how can I ask a summary for every variables that I have (protein, fat, starch, etc...) all in once?

Thank you very much!

Comment: something like `aggregate(protein~product,FUN = function(i) c(summary(i, na.rm = TRUE), l1 = length(i), sd1 = sd(i, na.rm = TRUE)), data=DATA4)`?

Comment: @Sotos

Thank you! It's working besides i cannot understand anything in the code.. x) 

But do know why now the answer is in this type of format?
aaa 6.400000e+00    1.470000e+01   1.560000e+01 1.554000e+01    1.660000e+01 (in exponential?)

Comment: You can avoid scientific notation by using `options(scipen=999)`

Comment: @Sotos

But where should I put that? In which part of the code? 
Sorry..  :/

Comment: just `options(scipen = 999) ; aggregate(.......))))`

Comment: @Sotos 
Thank you!! 
This solved my problem!

Comment: Sure. You might also want to review the dupe target for further info

Answer (score 2):

If I want to specify how I get the output of a summary I usually turn to a more elaborate solution using `dplyr` like so:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(product = rep(letters[1:3], each=3,3),
                 protein = sample(10:40, 27, replace=T))

df %>% group_by(product) %>% 
  summarise(min = min(protein)
            ,max = max(protein)
            ,mean = mean(protein)
            ,sd = sd(protein)
            ,n = n()
            ,q25 = quantile(protein, .25)
            ,q75 = quantile(protein, .75))
```

result:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 8
  product   min   max     mean       sd     n   q25   q75
   <fctr> <int> <int>    <dbl>    <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1       a    16    39 24.66667 8.717798     9    17    30
2       b    24    40 31.55556 5.387743     9    26    35
3       c    13    38 26.66667 8.108637     9    22    31
```

Comment: and you could adapt this to `summarise_all(funs(min, max, median, sd, n = n(), q25 = quantile(., .25), q75 = quantile(., .75)))` is you wanted to apply it to all of the categories (protein, fat and starch) in the original data frame

Comment: @Wietze314  Thank you for your help!

In your case i can see that is working but when i run that code i get this error:
Error in function_list[[i]](value) : could not find function "group_by"

Comment: you want to call `library(dplyr)` those functions are from that package

Comment: @Wietze314 I know and i did that already... 
and when i try again...same error.

Comment: Are your packages up to date? Maybe you need to update

Comment: I added the `library(dplyr)`. But I do not understand what is going wrong, did you change `df` to `DATA4`? since your data seems to be stored in a different variable.